# Загрузка ЦП и ОЗУ

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Нет ли, например, у хрома API для получения загрузки процессора и использования памяти через Javacript (текущей вкладки)?
Разрабатывается приложение на ExtJS и хотелось бы мониторить и логировать такие вещи.

Comment: Чувствую нехорошую штуку вы пишите раз такие вопросы задаёте...

Comment: @t1nk, а может наоборот?

ОС будущего -- действительно распределенные вычисления в P2P.

Comment: @avp, ждем WebCL - он точно вам с этим поможет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такого API нет (у браузера другие задачи вообще-то), но можно написать плагин.
К тому же обычно в подобных приложениях выводится загруженность сервера, а не клиентской машины. И я не могу представить зачем следить за пользователем из браузера...
Да и в любом случае собирать данные о клиенте без его ведома не есть хорошо. 
А если очень хочется, то для этого можно использовать и обычные средства распределенного мониторинга, типа [Zabbix](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FZabbix&ei=MuqJU7-WDLHc4QTwjoCIBQ&usg=AFQjCNEPofPrIzV6uwVE8WuE_esY_zRavQ&bvm=bv.67720277,d.bGE). И только с ведома пользователя.

Comment: да ТС наверное профилирование нужно, в хроме есть, встроенное.